# How do I delete from a table in JAVA JDBC based on conditions of two columns?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So I have been trying to delete a row from a table based on the values that exist in two columns. These two values being the customer name and the date which is passed in through a function. This function will delete the row which matches this criteria. The problem I am having is with the syntax of the prepared statement. Here are what I have tried:

```
 PreparedStatement stmt1 = myConn.prepareStatement("delete from SCHEDULE where CUSTOMER = ?,DATE = ?");
            stmt1.setString(1, customer);
            stmt1.setString(2, date);
            stmt1.executeUpdate();
```

I have also tried:

```
PreparedStatement stmt1 = myConn.prepareStatement("delete from SCHEDULE where CUSTOMER,DATE = ?,?");
            stmt1.setString(1, customer);
            stmt1.setString(2, date);
            stmt1.executeUpdate();
```

But nothing happens when I do this. I have seen in previous examples such as updating that this syntax has worked such as:

```
("UPDATE items SET name = ?, category = ?, price = ?, quantity = ? WHERE id = ?");
```

But is this not the case when using the keyword WHERE?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `AND` to join two conditions in `where`, your query would look like this:

`delete from SCHEDULE where CUSTOMER = ? and DATE = ?`